# Azure Data Factory HTTP endpoint to CosmosDB error converting datetime

Tags: datetime-format, azure-data-factory

I have a HTTP endpoint that returns data including a date time in the format:

```
"RowInsertDateTime": "2018-09-10T15:31:21.223",
```

I have had the data factory pipeline fail to import this row as a DATETIME due to this error:

> ```
> "message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorInvalidDataValue,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=,Source=,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
> ```
>
> 'RowInsertDateTime' contains an invalid value
>   '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33'. Cannot convert '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33' to
>   type 'DateTime' with format
>   'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String
>   was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
>   'RowInsertDateTime' contains an invalid value
>   '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33'. Cannot convert '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33' to
>   type 'DateTime' with format
>   'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String
>   was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
>   'RowInsertDateTime' contains an invalid value
>   '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33'. Cannot convert '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33' to
>   type 'DateTime' with format
>   'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String
>   was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Column
>   'RowInsertDateTime' contains an invalid value
>   '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33'. Cannot convert '2018-09-10T15:39:50.33' to
>   type 'DateTime' with format
>   'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String
>   was not recognized as a valid DateTime.,Source=mscorlib,'",

I have tried setting a format of YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS, but I get the same failure. Any ideas? I thought the date time format was valid.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have milliseconds in a date, so can you try using this format "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff"

Comment: Cannot convert '2018-09-03T00:00:47.02' to type 'DateTime' with format 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid

Comment: the first parameter contains 3 digits of milliseconds because of that I put .fff. In your comment, you have only .02 so that means you need to put .ff
If your DateTime format is not constant that you can just let him parse it without specified format.

check docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#the-ff-custom-format-specifier

Comment: The milliseconds may vary in length, but what do you mean by parse it without specified format? If I do that, it still fails (if I put no format) which is what led me to try formatting in the first place! This is the error without formatting - Message=Column 'RowInsertDateTime' contains an invalid value '2018-09-03T00:00:47.02'. Cannot convert '2018-09-03T00:00:47.02' to type 'DateTime' with format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff'.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Oh yes, if you don't specify the format, it will use default one, and that's "o".

Comment: Hmmm. Ok. So if I don't specify a format, it doesn't work. If I specify the format you suggested, it doesn't work. So, what's my option here? If anything? :/

Comment: Maybe to clean data before adf, so every date value is in the same format. ADF doesn't have tools for some deep smart logic :) Its only for orchestration/copying. Or I am not aware of them :)))

Comment: Agree with DraganB. If you datetime format is not fixed, could you just write it as string, instead of datetime? And then handle the datetime value at cosmos db side.